# EFI Memory Map returns 0 sections of EFIConventionalMemory

Tags: c++, operating-system, bootloader, uefi, gnu-efi

As stated in the title, getting the EFI Memory Map in a UEFI bootloader is yielding no sections of EFIConventionalMemory. If I'm not mistaken, this should be the majority of the memory?

It is returning this on both QEMU and on real hardware. Setting QEMU to have 2GB RAM causes a memory segment of ACPIReclaimMemory to be made up of most of this memory (2009MB of ACPI reclaimable) which seems absurd to me. Is this the intended behaviour or is there something wrong?

Thanks.

Edit: this is the type list that I'm using

```
const char* EFI_MEMORY_TYPE_STRINGS[] {
"EfiReservedMemoryType",
"EfiRuntimeServicesCode",
"EfiRuntimeServicesData",
"EfiMemoryMappedIO",  
"EfiMemoryMappedIOPortSpace",
"EfiPalCode",
"EfiUnusableMemory",
"EfiACPIReclaimMemory",
"EfiLoaderCode",
"EfiLoaderData", 
"EfiBootServicesCode",
"EfiBootServicesData",
"EfiConventionalMemory",
"EfiACPIMemoryNVS"  
};
```

Comment: Can you post your code and the memory map of one system?

Comment: Are you sure you’re using the right type value? Conventional memory is 7.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @prl if conventional memory is 7 then everything is okay. From the type list I have, conventional memory is 12 and ACPI reclaimable memory is 7. I will edit the post to show my type list.

Comment: Okay, it turns out my memory type list was incorrect. It's solved now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The memory type list was incorrect. Here is the correct EFI_MEMORY_TYPE_STRINGS:

```
const char* EFI_MEMORY_TYPE_STRINGS[] {
"EfiReservedMemoryType",
"EfiLoaderCode",
"EfiLoaderData",
"EfiBootServicesCode",
"EfiBootServicesData",
"EfiRuntimeServicesCode",
"EfiRuntimeServicesData",
"EfiConventionalMemory",
"EfiUnusableMemory",
"EfiACPIReclaimMemory",
"EfiACPIMemoryNVS",
"EfiMemoryMappedIO",
"EfiMemoryMappedIOPortSpace",
"EfiPalCode",
};
```

Thanks everyone for your help